# Django Url Not Resolving with Query Parameters

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I have an issue where I need to pass in query parameters for a GET request, but Django is not resolving the URL correctly to the view.

My urls.py looks like this:

```
   from django.conf.urls.defaults import * 
   urlpatterns = patterns('',
       url(r'^confirm_cancel',
          'myapp.views.confirm_cancel_method',
           name='myapp_confirm_cancel'),
       )
```

When I goto /confirm_cancel?some_id=x I get a 404, telling me "No MyModel matches query."  When I set a breakpoint in my view handler, it does not get hit when I goto that url.

However, if I goto /confirm_cancel/x/, my view breakpoint does get hit.

One more thing to note, this worked in Django 1.1, but is now broken since I upgraded to 1.2.

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: Post view code if you don't want people wasting their time guessing things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had copied out all the other url patterns in the urls.py in my post.

Turns out that the issue was that I had a `r'^(?P<my_id>\w+)/?$'` for one of the urls at the top of the `urlpatterns`.

Next time I'll learn to paste everything instead of cherry picking what I think are the offending lines of code.

Strange that this did not cause Django 1.1 to break... I guess it was a bug that was fixed in 1.2

Comment: Glad it's fixed.  Go ahead and accept your own answer so the question is considered solved (and the solution apparent for other people facing this issue).

Comment: I very nearly asked whether there was a matching url pattern earlier in the list.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the problem is with your url.  Are you using a shortcut like `get_object_or_4o4` somewhere in your view?  For example:

```
get_object_or_404(MyModel, pk=99)
```

would result in a "No MyModel matches given query, if there wasn't a record in your table with a primary key of 99.

Comment: Yes, I'm using get_object_or_404(), but before that line is hit I put in a debug breakpoint, and that breakpoint is not getting hit at all.  So that's not where it's throwing the 404.

Comment: Trying to narrow it down ... The error message you pasted indicates a problem with a *model* not being found, not the URL handler.  It might help to paste your view code and the entire stack trace instead.

Answer (score 1):

We need to see what's in the corresponding view function.

Ideally, it should look something like this:

```
def confirm_cancel_method(request, some_id=None):
    some_id = request.REQUEST.get('some_id', some_id)
    some_record = get_object_or_404(SomeModel, pk=some_id)
    ...
```

**update**

Sorry, just saw your note about the breakpoint. One thing I'd recommend is changing the config to this:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import * 
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^confirm_cancel/?$',
       'myapp.views.confirm_cancel_method',
        name='myapp_confirm_cancel'),
    )
```

Adding `/?$` at the end means that only `/confirm_cancel` or `/confirm_cancel/` will match the url. Right now because you don't have the ending `$` anything starting with `confirm_cancel` will match. Fixing the pattern will at least resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if this was a case of the [trailing slash](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/?from=olddocs#append-slash)?

Comment: Yep, slash or no slash, it still fails.